# Meu App não carrega lista de itens

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin-forms

Tenho uma `App Xamarin.Forms`que consome dois serviços `rest`. O primeiro serviço, consome normalmente. Porém o segundo, que preciso passar um parâmetro, esse não está sendo consumido. Já tentei de várias formas e não funciona. Sei que o meu código está bugado, mas não sei onde, não sei como fazer consumir o serviço. A variável `_data` que vai preencher o **Grid** com as informações, não está vindo preenchida e sim nula. Abaixo meus códigos:
Meu data service que deveria carregar os itens da URL:

```
public async Task<List<ItensLib>> GetItensLibAsync(int idorcamento)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/itens/{idorcamento}";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItensLib>>(response);
                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Minha chamada no construtor da classe xaml.cs do meu App

```
public MainPageItens(int idorcamento)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IdOrcamento = idorcamento;

            CarregaDados(idorcamento);
....

async void CarregaDados(int idorcamento)
        {
            _data = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento);
        }
```

Meu construtor completo, com a montagem do **Grid**

```
public MainPageItens(int idorcamento)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IdOrcamento = idorcamento;

            CarregaDados(idorcamento);

            // Crete a grid for "title"
            Grid grid = CreateGrid();
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Produto", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 0, 1, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 1, 2, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Qtde", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 2, 3, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 3, 4, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Unitário", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 4, 5, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 5, 6, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Custo", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 6, 7, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 7, 8, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Custo Dia", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 8, 9, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 9, 10, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Ult. Vencto", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 10, 11, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 11, 12, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Total", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 12, 13, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 13, 14, 0, 1);

            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorH(), 0, 14, 1, 2);

            // Create the ListView to visualize my data
            ListView lv = new ListView() { HasUnevenRows = true, SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None };
            lv.ItemsSource = _data;
            lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListViewTemplateGrid));

            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout() { Children = { grid, lv }, Spacing = 0 };

            this.Content = sl;
        }
```

Essa é a declaração da property _data no início da classe:

```
List<ItensLib> _data { get; set; }
List<ItensLib> _itens ;
DataService dataService;
```

Aqui está o screenshot do erro(Não diz nada), como eu sei que `_data` está `null`, acho que é esse o problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1**
Eu sobrescrevi o método OnAppering e retirei do Construtor a chamada e a construção do Grid e passei para esse método. E no método CarregaDados, passei ele para `async Task CarregaDados(int idorcamento);`. O que passa é a chamada no OnAppering desse método está dando esse erro:

> o operador 'wait' só pode ser usado em um método assíncrono.

Veja como ficou:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await CarregaDados(IdOrcamento);**Aqui dá erro**

            // Crete a grid for "title"
            Grid grid = CreateGrid();
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Produto", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 0, 1, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 1, 2, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Qtde", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 2, 3, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 3, 4, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Unitário", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 4, 5, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 5, 6, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Custo", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 6, 7, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 7, 8, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Custo Dia", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 8, 9, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 9, 10, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Ult. Vencto", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 10, 11, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 11, 12, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Total", TextColor = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center }, 12, 13, 0, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 13, 14, 0, 1);

            grid.Children.Add(SeparatorH(), 0, 14, 1, 2);

            // Create the ListView to visualize my data
            ListView lv = new ListView() { HasUnevenRows = true, SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None };
            lv.ItemsSource = _data;
            lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListViewTemplateGrid));

            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout() { Children = { grid, lv }, Spacing = 0 };

            this.Content = sl;
        }
```

E o método CarregaDados:

```
async Task CarregaDados(int idorcamento)
        {
            _data = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento);
        }
```

Comment: Só uma pergunta: carregaDados é um método async, mas está sendo chamado de dentro de um construtor. Será que isso não contribui para o problema? Pois construtores não aceitam, pelo menos declaração de qualquer coisa async, assim entendo eu. Se for isso, como eu faço para construir meu **Grid** no momento em que a classe é instanciada ?

Comment: Vou reiniciar o VS ou o PC

Comment: Qual a plataforma que você está executando o aplicativo, android, ios ou WP? Pq a resposta depende essencialmente desta informação.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, uso Xamarin.Forms(Cross Platform), mas só consigo testar no Android

Answer (score 2):

Conforme resposta do comentário, segue possível solução:

No android verifique o seguinte:

1. Tem que ter a permissão de internet no manifest;
2. Toda chamada de internet tem que ser feita em uma AsyncTask ou qualquer outra background task. No seu caso, pelo código, ela está sendo feita diretamente na tela. Então recomendo criar uma AsyncTask (não o task do Xamarin, mas a classe AsyncTask do android) e depois fazer a chamada dentro dela. Segue um exemplo de classe.

`public class BgTask : AsyncTask<String, Java.Lang.Void, String>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Método que vai fazer a chamada em background
    /// </summary>
    protected override String RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Executado depois que o RunInBackground terminar, geralmente usado para retornar o resultado.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)
    {
    }
}`

A chamada desta task fica

```
new BgTask().execute("param");
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso: sobreescrvi o método OnAppearing() e passei tudo do meu construtor para esse método. Mas o problema todo estava nessa linha, um erro elementar que não poderia ter acontecido: Eu fiz: `DataService dataService` e deveria ser `DataService dataService = new DataService()`

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que quando teu código chega aqui:

```
lv.ItemsSource = _data;
```

...o método `CarregaDados(idorcamento)` que foi chamado algumas linhas acima ainda não executou, nem populou a variável `_data`. Você precisa esperar esse método terminar sua execução, por exemplo:

```
Task.Run(async () => await CarregaDados(idorcamento)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Essa é uma forma de executar *sincronamente* um método assíncrono, que é o caso do `CarregaDados`.